# Magento editor automatic line break issue while adding new product

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I'm adding a new product in Magento CE 1.7.0.2. I entered the HTML code in *Short Description* attribute.

**MY PROBLEM:** I really don't know where these extra `<br>` coming from. Even the WYSIWYG editor is not showing these `<br>` but they are appearing on the website's product page. Please help.

**WHAT I ENTERED:**

```
<p>Product Description:</p>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5px">
    <tr>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>Specials</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Texure</td>
        <td>Digitally Printed on High Quality Matte Paper</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**WHAT IT IS DISPLAYING:**

```
<p>Product Description:</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5px">
    <tr>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>Specials</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Texure</td>
        <td>Digitally Printed on High Quality Matte Paper</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: have you seen the css rules ??

Comment: and when you enter it in editor, try to swich to code view, and see what happens there

Comment: @NewBee CSS can't add `<br>` elements. WYSIWYG editor & code view, both doesn't have any <br> elements.

Answer (score 2):

These additional breaks are caused by `nl2br()` function that should be removed.

To resolve this for **short description**, open app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml, find:

`<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?>`

and replace this by:

`<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>`

To resolve this for **description**, open app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml, find:

`<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), nl2br($_description), 'description') ?>`

and relace this by:

`<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description') ?>`

[Source](https://www.designhaven.co.uk/2012/08/removing-automatic-line-breaks-from-magentos-product-descriptions/)