# magento short description automatic line break issue when selecting associated product

Tags: php, html, magento

**Story:**

> User goes to the product page of the configurable product which has 4
>   dropdowns and many associated simple products. At this point the
>   short description of the configurable product looks just like I left it in WYSIWYG. However, after
>   the user selects any value in any of the dropdowns - additional `<br>`
>   elements get added in between `<li>` elements.

**HTML before:**

```
<ul>
  <li>Text1</li>
  <li>Text2</li>
  <li>Text3</li>
  <li>Text4</li>
</ul>
```

**HTML after:**

```
<ul>
  <br>
  <li>Text1</li>
  <br>
  <li>Text2</li>
  <br>
  <li>Text3</li>
  <br>
  <li>Text4</li>
  <br>
</ul>
```

> This is a very similar issue to
>   [Magento editor automatic line break issue while adding new product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718649/magento-editor-automatic-line-break-issue-while-adding-new-product),
>   but the difference is that I have already removed the nl2br() from the
>   view.phtml file and my issue only occurs after the value is selected
>   in one of the dropdowns on the product page.

**Questions:**

- Is there any other file that could call nl2br() on product page update?
- What else could cause this kind of behaviour?
- How to prevent Magento from adding the break elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated the issue and found out that Magento kept inserting `<br>` elements between `<p>` elements, so I came up with a **workaround** which was to **only ever have one paragraph `<p>` and visually fake the notion of paragraphs using `<br>` elements** myself where I want them to be.